# MPI OpenMp hybrid

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, openmp

I am trying to run a program written for MPI and OpenMP on a cluster of Linux dual cores.

When I try to set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
```

I get a message

> OMP_NUM_THREADS: Undefined variable.

I don't get a better performance with OpenMP... I also tried:

```
mpiexec -n 10 -genv OMP_NUM_THREADS 2 ./binary
```

and `omp_set_num_threads(2)` inside the program, but it didn't get any better...
Any ideas?

update: when I run `mpiexec -n 1 ./binary` with `omp_set_num_threads(2)` execution time is 4s and when I run `mpiexec -f machines -n 1 ./binary` execution time is 8s.

Comment: You should change some of your **bold** text to be `code`.

Comment: much better thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing an `$echo OMP_NUM_THREADS` first and further querying for the number of threads inside the program to make sure that threads are being spawned. Use the `omp_get_num_threads()` function for this. Further if you're using a MacOS then this blogpost can help:
https://whiteinkdotorg.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/installing-mpich-using-macports-on-mac-os-x/
The latter part in this post will help you to successfully compile and run Hybrid programs. Whether a Hybrid program gets better performance or not depends a lot on contention of resources. Excessive usage of locks, barriers - can further slow the program down. It will be great if you post your code here for others to view and to actually help you.

Comment: `omp_get_num_threads()` returns 1 for all the processes...also tried `mpicc -cc=gcc -fopenmp` but nothing changed

Comment: @orestiss Are you sure you make the call in the parallel region?

Comment: @orestiss You might also try to call `omp_get_max_threads()` outside a parallel region.

Comment: `omp_get_num_threads()` in parallel region returns 2 also `omp_get_max_threads()` out of the parallel region. When I run the program for 1 process with the openmp loop enabled I get half the time, (better performance). When I run it for more processes it get's slower... maybe there is some problem with the cluster configuration