# How OpenMP can be run through mpi?

Tags: mpi, openmp, hybrid

I am having a code where part of the code uses MPI another part uses OpenMP. I followed ([MPI OpenMp hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181069/mpi-openmp-hybrid)) link and several others, but could not do what I need. When the MPI part performs computation OpenMP does not do anything and vice versa.

I could compile the code successfully.

Now suppose I run the code with

```
mpirun -np 4 ./program
```

How can I run the code such that when the code encounters the OpenMP part it runs in the same number of threads like that of np?

Comment: Which MPI library are you using?

Comment: Basically, it does not work this way. If you have let's say 8 cores, you would for example start 4 MPI tasks with 2 OpenMP threads each (and make sure if MPI does process binding, it gives at least two cores to each MPI task).

Comment: OpenMP @DmitriChubarov

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible or not depending on your machine. If you're running MPI on a single node, then read on. However, MPI is usually used for distributed memory, and then it is impossible to span OpenMP threads to handle that distributed data.

Now if you're running on a single node, you could use MPI shared memory, so that one process could access all the memory, and then use OpenMP threads to process this memory. See [https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-shared.html](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-shared.html)